# Rounding down with Time to a specific interval

Tags: go, time

I am using `time.Unix` for my time library in Go, but I am having trouble figuring out how to round down to a specific format. I have a function that takes input to time like this:

```
func roundTimeDown(startTime time.Time) string {
    tUnix:= startTime.Unix()

 }
```

But I would like to round it down to intervals of 5 mins (ending in 30 seconds). For example, 9:57:30, 10:02:30, 10:07:30, etc.

So, if a user sends 10:08 into the function, it'll round down to 10:07:30. How can I do that?

Answer (score 1):

Looks like a job for [`Time.Truncate`](https://golang.org/pkg/time/#Time.Truncate).

Comment: Any chance you can provide an example of how I can do this to the specific time interval? It's the 30 seconds that is throwing me off..